# How to send Intent to: <service android:name="com.some.example.SomeService" android:exported="true" />

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello and thanks very much in advance for any help.

I'm trying to figure out how to send an Intent to an exported service that resides in another application. The service has no intent-filters or other attributes. Just a name and exported="true".

I know how to do this when the service specifies a unique action. But, in this case, I have nothing but the service name. I know it sounds a bit strange. Why would I want to do this. But, I'm trying to launch the service before launching the main app so that I can observe behavior. I've tried everything I can think of and googled for several days now to now avail.

Thanks very much again for the help.